# onBeforeHide event is not triggering in dhtmlx popup

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I'm trying to work with `dhtmlx popup` and according to requirement,

> popup should stay in place even if outside popup area is clicked

. Using `onBeforeHide` event for this case but it is not triggering.

Pls help!! I'm using dhtmlx version 3.6.

Regards,
Shalini Mathur

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suppose I'll be the one to say it: please post *specific code* so we can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function sdrComment(sdrButton){
    var vParentOrder = null;
    var row_id = myGrid.getSelectedId();
    if( (row_id == "") || (row_id == null)) {
        alert("Please select an order");
        return;
    }
    vParentOrder = myGrid.cellById(row_id, 0).getValue();
    var url =  "/XMII/Illuminator?QueryTemplate=NC/sqlSDRCommentsForOrder&Param.1=" + vParentOrder + "&Content-Type=text/json"; 
    var returnData = callAjaxReturn(url);   
    var sdrComments;
    sdrComments = returnData.Rowsets.Rowset [0].Row [0].sdrComments;
    if((sdrComments == "") || (sdrComments == null)){
        alert("No SDR comment exists for selected order");
    }
    else{
        var myPop;
        var myForm;
        var formData;
        formData = [{
                    type: "block",
                style: "margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;",
                list: [
            {type: "settings",inputWidth: 300,inputHeight: 300},
                            {type: "input",name: "memo",value: sdrComments,rows: 3,readonly: true},
            {type: "button", value: "OK"}]
        }];
var flag_hide = 0;
    myPop = new dhtmlXPopup({ id: "popforsdr" });
        myPop.attachEvent("onShow", function(){
            if (myForm == null) {
                myForm = myPop.attachForm(formData);
                myForm.setFontSize("19px");
                myForm.attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(){
                    myPop.hide();
                    flag_hide = 1;
                    Permissions(true);
                    selectable = true;
                });
            }

        });
        myPop.attachEvent("onBeforeHide", function(){
        //alert("Hide");
        return false;
    /*  if(flag_hide == 0){
        myPop.show();
        }
        else{
        myPop.hide();
        flag_hide = 0;
        }
*/

        });
              var x = getAbsoluteLeft(sdrButton);
            var y = getAbsoluteTop(sdrButton);
            var w = sdrButton.offsetWidth;
            var h = sdrButton.offsetHeight;
            myPop.show(x, y, w, h);
        Permissions(false);
        selectable = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find reference code,

```
myPop.attachEvent("onBeforeHide", function(){
    return false;
});
```

In this line I'm trying for popup to stay.